# Add a variable in an existing variable name in javascript

Tags: javascript

in the beginning i declare a variable like this:

```
var content = "likes";

var main_likes_data = true;
```

And later i want to change the variable to false, but i need to add a new variable like this:

```
main_" + content + "_data = false;
```

But this does not work!

Can someone please tell me the right sytax to change the variable?

Thank You!!!

Comment: This is Javascript; nothing to do with jquery.

Answer (score 4):

You need an associative array.

```
var content = "likes";
var main_data = {
   likes: true,
   somethingelse: false,
   xyz: false
};

main_data[content] = false;
```

Comment: Thanks, but i do not need to change the content variable, i need to change the main_likes_data variable ;)

Comment: And why can't you change `main_likes_data` to be an array? Thing is, I assume that your have lots of these: `main_somethingelse_data`, `main_xyz_data` etc. If so, then you've made life hard for yourself by not using arrays, so I would take a step back and fix the issue at its root cause.

Comment: Thank You! That is right i habe more variables like main_somethingelse_data or main_xyz_data. In your code i dont understand why you have likes: true
 in the array and why the variable is written like main_data[content] = false;
 and not main_likes_data = true;?

Comment: This does not change the variable name ;)

Comment: @Mario See the edited example. `main_data` is one object that stores many boolean values, instead of all your existing variables. Hope that makes it clearer. I recommend reading up on how Javascript objects and arrays work.

Comment: Thanks but i need to create the right syntax for a dynamic variable name like this: main_" + content + "_data = false;

Comment: @Mario, I don't think you really *need* to do that.  If you want to declare a variable, then you need to explicitly declare it: `var main_something_data`.  If you don't explicitly declare it, then it doesn't exist.  If you need an undetermined number of variables, then you need to use an array, and Tim's answer provides a way for you to do that.  http://blog.xkoder.com/2008/07/10/javascript-associative-arrays-demystified/

Answer (score 0):

```
window["main_" + content + "_data"] = true;
```

This works as

a) variables created without a defined scope are, by default, scoped against the `window` object
 b) You can use the square bracket notation in javascript interchangably with the dot notation. The square bracket notation takes a string. The string can be concatenated using variables.

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/bX5Zy/

Comment: This is a the same as Tim Rogers' solution but it's accessing the global scope. (Which can be treated as an array) You probably want to declare one array inside of your desired scope that contains these values though, and not pollute the global scope with x variables.

Comment: @ManseUK - It didnt work as you scoped all your javascript into an `onLoad` and therefore variables created with `var` get scoped to the `onLoad` function. Without scoping it (ie, just head, nowrap) works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/bX5Zy/

Comment: @Jamiec so in other words - this only works if you define the variable as global ....

Comment: Thanks, but i need to the right syntaxfor a dynamic variable like this: main_" + content + "_data = false;

Answer (score 0):

It's really bad programming practice, but you could use eval:

```
eval("main_" + content + "_data = false");
```

I personally would not use `eval` myself, but other people would. To quote John Resig:

> “Overwhelmingly [eval is] trivailized, misused, and outright condemned
>   by most JavaScript programmers but by looking at the work of some of
>   the best coders you can see that , when used appropriately [it] allows
>   for the creation of some fantastic pieces of code that wouldn’t be
>   possible otherwise”

John Resig, in [Secrets of the JavaScript Ninja](http://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:OZgEGrXotyQJ:www.manning-source.com/books/resig/resig_meapch1.pdf%20resig%20overwhelmingly%20trivialized%20eval&hl=en&gl=us&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEEShR4HHvCRg6bsSdgOYZHLrBPKAEsecgd1dEzJQwvl6KRUnbTjEGLBB4Ym3g7cjI4Zz2xnFfNrYE3cM2imPHJjIvURxl97okzb3pnPhgeaA5FM2_dZxk3WItS70RSCjI59pAeUus&sig=AHIEtbSLhP0EQn81ozLtugYYr6OaNlKWlQ)

Comment: The question to begin with is bogus... but does it answer the question? Um... yes! Why -1 me for an answer that works?

Comment: @ManseUK It's up to the OP to use it or not, just giving him an answer that works. I'm not the code police.

Comment: When there is 0 need for eval then there is 0 need to teach poor coding practices to beginners.

Comment: Thanks but i need to create the right syntax for a dynamic variable name like this: main_" + content + "_data = false;

Comment: Ok, this finaly works ;) But why is everyone saying that this is evil? ;)